# @PropertyResource is not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties, spring-annotations

Below is my Property class:

```
package com.example.sdasDemo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:info.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "feeder")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Properties {
    public String[] id;
}
```

Below is the simple controller:

```
package com.example.sdasDemo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class controller {
    @Autowired
    Properties properties;

    @RequestMapping("/get")
    public String getData(){
        System.out.println(properties.getId());
        return properties.getId();
    }
}
```

Below is the info.properties file

```
feeder.id=soumik,das,21022021
```

http://localhost:8080/get returns **null pointer exception**

Why this @PropertyResouce is not working? What am I missing here. Please suggest.

Comment: Because that property should be in the `application.properties` or loaded through Spring Boot and not through `@PropertySource`. So remove the `@PropertySource` and either move the properties to `application.properties` or add this property file to the list of files to be loaded by spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was happening due to wrong profile name provided. For that reason, the property file location could not be found and resulting null pointer exception.